# How to debug CodeIgniter app with PhpStorm

Tags: php, nginx, phpstorm, xdebug

I am unable to initiate a debug session with my CodeIgniter application. I am using nginx, PHP, and PhpStorm. There are configuration files:

**nginx:**

```
server {
        server_name localhost;
        listen 8300;
        root /Users/admin/WORK/fabtbackoffice;
        index index.html index.php;

        # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
        location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location / {
                # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9005;
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "xdebug.remote_enable=1\nxdebug.idekey=idea";
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

**php-fpm config:**

```ini
[wordpress_site]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9005
listen.owner = Admin
listen.group = Admin
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 75
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
```

**php.ini file:**

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
; xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
; xdebug.client_port=9000
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.client_enable=1
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9000
```

I tried to debug my app through PhpStorm. I have Xdebug and web browser extension installed and configured. Also in VSCode everything works well.

Comment: *"Also in VSCode everything works well."* If it works in VSCode then you need to show your PhpStorm settings for debugging. Most likely they use different settings (e.g. listen on different Xdebug ports or whatnot). Also check 1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/

Comment: Thank you for the reply, there are my configs for phpstorm
https://imgur.com/nVmsHV9
https://imgur.com/V2Q7kPK

Comment: Also validation page https://imgur.com/a/jXDcR7s

Comment: Alright everything works well now, after i have double checked all my settings